# Is it possible to have separate icons for Openbox active and inactive windows?

Tags: icons, themes, openbox

Pretty sure this is not the place to ask such a question, but I did not find any Openbox forums.

Anyways, I am wondering if anyone knows if it is possible to have separate icons for the Openbox window decorations (close, minimize etc.). For example, if the window is active I want to have a circle as the close button, but when the window is inactive, a square.

**EDIT:**

To clarify a bit, I have created an Openbox theme according to this guide:
http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Themes

I am wondering if there is a way of adding additional XBM files for the active and inactive windows. http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Themes#Button_images

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]